# SSH into a VM instance managed by an Instance Group in GCP without Owner IAM permission on the project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I've given myself compute instance admin V1 permissions, as well as service account admin. I can ssh into single VM instances that are not managed by any MiG, but somehow for all MiG managed instances, the SSH button is greyed out. I've tried Compute OS Login and Compute Admin Login permissions as well without any success.

It works when I give myself Owner permission on the project, but I would like to avoid that. Is there any IAM setting that will allow me to SSH into a MiG managed VM? Google documentation is not very helpful on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to SSH into machine after you grant yourself `roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1` and `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`.

Take a look at [Granting users SSH access to VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access#granting_users_ssh_access_to_vm_instances) and [Managed instance groups and IAM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#managedinstancegroupiam).

You can also access your VMs via [serial console](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b).

Comment: Hm, it seems like the SSH button for mig instances is still greyed out with these permissions. I can SSH to a non Mig single VM, but not a VM that's part of a MiG

Comment: Can you access that VM via serial port?